# Multiple Ancova's and adjustments to p-values

Tags: p-value, bootstrap, ancova

I am running about 10 Ancova's and am unsure about whether I adjust the overall p-value and then also the posthoc analyses p values. If the categorical independent factor has 3 or more levels. do I use bonferoni? Familywise scheffe?...
I also have bootstrapped the data in the Ancova.